# add a class attribute to `<xsl:element>` under a certain condition

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to add a class to `<xsl:element>` under a certain condition, I've an xml tag with an attribute called def, I need to add a class when ever this attribute exists.

Here is the xslt element:

```
<xsl:element name="{if (@id='123') then 'th' else 'td'} >
<xsl:apply-template />
</xsl:element>
```

What i've tried:

```
<xsl:attribute name="class">def-
        <xsl:if test="fn:exists(@def)">
        <xsl:value-of select="@def"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:element name="{if (@role='rowhead' ) then 'th' else 'td'}" use-attribute-sets="{$class}" >
<xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
```

I would like a matching expression of this:

```
<th scope="row" class="def-{if (fn:exists(@def)) then @def else ''}">
<td scope="row" class="def-{if (fn:exists(@def)) then @def else ''}">
```

using:

```
<xsl:element>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you expect your output to look like? Also, if you show your input XML too, that would help alot too. Thanks!

Comment: @TimC I've edited my question, please check it out.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dynamically create an attribute based on certain conditions, re-jig your code to this...

```
<xsl:element name="{if (@role='rowhead' ) then 'th' else 'td'}">   
    <xsl:if test="fn:exists(@def)">
       <xsl:attribute name="class" select="concat('def-', @def)"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:element>
```

If you use `xsl:attribute` immediately after `xsl:element` the attribute gets appended on to the element. Note that attributes must be created before any child elements.

Comment: Thanks, if i may ask whats the usage of use-attribute-sets="{$class}"

Comment: It's when you have a set of attributes, defined by `xsl:attribute-set` that you want to add to easily add to multiple elements. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-sets